Add number variable to template with prefix, suffix and currency
I have added a number field with prefix, suffix and currency symbol:

How can I add a variable to a template which shows the number with prefix, suffix and currency? I tried the following which didn't work:
{{ entry.rentalPrice|money }}
I couldn't find the information in the documentation: https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/reference/field-types/number.html

Fetching the field and outputting the following should work.
{% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('my-field-handle') %}
{{ field.prefix }}
{{ entry.rentalPrice }}
{{ field.suffix }}
{{ field.previewCurrency }}

Class reference: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v5/craft-fields-number.html#public-properties

Thank you. Unfortunately, for me it doesn't work. I am using CraftCMS 5.x. I get an error: Twig Runtime Error – Twig\Error\RuntimeError / Impossible to access an attribute ("prefix") on a integer variable ("175"). / Impossible to access an attribute ("suffix") on a integer variable ("175"). / Impossible to access an attribute ("previewCurrency") on a integer variable ("175"). Even better would be to have just one variable that will show the field value including prefix, suffix and currency.

I also tried {{ entry.rentalPrice.currency ?? null }} which neither produces an error nor shows any data. I have set a value for prefix, suffix and currency so it shouldn't be empty.

Oh right, I forgot that the normalised value is returned. I updated my answer to fetch the field itself.

Thank you! It works but it is a lot of code for one field. According to this documentation it should be craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle instead of craft.app.fields.fieldByHandle: https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/reference/twig/global-variables.html

Both work, but I updated my answer to match the docs. It’s really just one line of code to get the field. The rest is to output it in whatever format you want.
